# Query to find document ID through Box API (using cURL or python)

Tags: api, curl, box-api

This should be a relatively easy question. I have documents in my Box account that I'd like to  view on a webpage. To do so I need the document ID. Is there an easy way to find the document id? I'm using this documentation http://developers.box.com/docs/ and tried:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files \ 
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

But I receive a `couldn't resolve host` error.

My document resides in a folder as well. Will I need to query something different to find the document id found inside a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the API call you're looking for. This will return you file IDs for every file in a specified folder:

http://developers.box.com/docs/#folders-retrieve-a-folders-items

You've got a few options for finding the folder ID. You can use the root folder, which has an ID of 0, so you can get the files and folders in there and continue inspecting your Box account based on those Ids. Or you can use the search API endpoint to search by keyword and return folder and file IDs.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#search-searching-a-users-account

Comment: Thanks, but how do you know what the folder id is? Is this given to me somehow?

Comment: Sorry about that - I edited my answer above to include the info on finding a folder ID. One approach I didn't mention is that if you know the folder, and the folder won't change, then you could probably just get the folder ID from the URL string in your browser.